# Git blame for deleted section

Tags: git, git-blame

I need to know who and when deleted some portion of a source file using git. Unfortunately, it seems git blame won't directly show me that, as said section is totally absent from file in the current revision. Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find commits which were changing something in lines having certain string. This way you can see which commit deleted some line if you know what its content was

```
git log -S <string> path/to/file
```

In order to find how exactly these lines were written you can see your file in some very old commit:

```
git show old-commit-hash^:src/path/to/file
```

Comment: Very useful option in general.

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of options here:

1. Use the [`-G`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#Documentation/git-log.txt--Gltregexgt) option of [`git log`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log) to find the commits that *added* or *removed* a line that matches the code that was deleted:

   ```
   git log -G"code that was deleted"
   ```

   where the specified string can also be a regular expression
2. Use the [`-L`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#Documentation/git-log.txt--Lltstartgtltendgtltfilegt) option with a line range to find the commits that modified those lines:

   ```
   git log -L10,20:path/to/file
   ```

   would list the commits that modified code between lines `10` and `20` in `path/to/file`
3. Use the `-L` option with the name of the function that was deleted:

   ```
   git log -Lfoo:path/to/file
   ```

   would list the commits that modified the `foo` function in `path/to/file`.

Once you know the commit that deleted that code, you can easily determine the author.